# Confluent: ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier mysql-jdbc

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use mode timestamp with MySQL, with limited rows as my table size is 2.6 GB.

Here are the connector properties that I am using:

```
{
        "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_registration_query",
        "config": {
                 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                 "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
                 "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
                 "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
                 "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
                 "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/users?zeroDateTimeBehavior=ROUND&useCursorFetch=true&defaultFetchSize=1000&user=kotesh&password=kotesh",
                 "query": "SELECT matriid,DateUpdated  from users.employee WHERE date(DateUpdated)>='2018-11-28' ",
                 "mode": "timestamp",
                 "timestamp.column.name": "DateUpdated",
                 "validate.non.null": "false",
                 "topic.prefix": "mysql-prod-kot-"
        }
}
```

I getting as below:

> INFO TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='SELECT
>   matriid,DateUpdated  from users.employee WHERE
>   date(DateUpdated)>='2018-11-28'', topicPrefix='mysql-prod-kot-',
>   incrementingColumn='', timestampColumns=[DateUpdated]} prepared SQL
>   query: SELECT matriid,DateUpdated  from users.employee WHERE
>   date(DateUpdated)>='2018-11-28' WHERE `DateUpdated` > ? AND
>   `DateUpdated` < ? ORDER BY `DateUpdated` ASC
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier:161)
>       [2018-11-29 17:29:00,981] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='SELECT
>   matriid,DateUpdated  from users.employee WHERE
>   date(DateUpdated)>='2018-11-28'', topicPrefix='mysql-prod-kot-',
>   incrementingColumn='', timestampColumns=[DateUpdated]}: {}
>   (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:328)
>       java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `DateUpdated` > '1970-01-01
>   00:00:00.0' AND `DateUpdated` < '2018-11-29 17' at line 1

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you are trying to use both `"mode": "timestamp"` and `query`. `TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier` appends a `WHERE` clause to the query that conflicts with existing `WHERE` clauses in the `query`.

[JDBC source connector docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html) is clear on this:

> `query`
>
> If specified, the query to perform to select new or updated rows. Use
>   this setting if you want to join tables, select subsets of columns in
>   a table, or filter data. If used, this connector will only copy data
>   using this query -- whole-table copying will be disabled. Different
>   query modes may still be used for incremental updates, but in order to
>   properly construct the incremental query, it must be possible to
>   append a WHERE clause to this query (i.e. no WHERE clauses may be
>   used). **If you use a WHERE clause, it must handle incremental queries
>   itself**.

As a workaround, you can modify your query to (depending on what SQL flavour are you using)

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...)
```

or

```
WITH a AS
   SELECT * FROM b
    WHERE ...
SELECT * FROM a
```

For example, in your case the query should be

```
"query":"SELECT * FROM (SELECT matriid,DateUpdated  from users.employee WHERE date(DateUpdated)>='2018-11-28') o"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is as shown:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'WHERE `DateUpdated` > '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND `DateUpdated` < '2018-11-29 17' at line 1
```

This is because you're using `query` but also `"mode": "timestamp"` and thus the connector tries to append it's own `WHERE` clause when you have also specified one in the query, which results in the invalid SQL

Per [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html#mode) for the JDBC source connector:

> in order to properly construct the incremental query, it must be possible to append a WHERE clause to this query (i.e. **no WHERE clauses may be used**). If you use a WHERE clause, it must handle incremental queries itself.

Comment: Follow up question - how do you specific the starting timestamp for the connector